# StockTwits Not Working in Slack

Tags: bots, slack, stocktwits

I cannot get access to Stocktwits through slack. I was able to add the channel, but when I make a call this pops up:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is not supported anymore. We have asked slack to take the app down but looks like they still haven't done so. We will build another one in the future. Sorry for the confusion.